# How to set a repeating alarm with a certain number of days?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

How to set a recurring alarm with a certain number of days, for example, every 27 days or 15 days

```
    switch (reminder.getRepeatType()) {
        case Reminder.HOURLY:
            calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, reminder.getInterval());
            break;
        case Reminder.DAILY:
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, reminder.getInterval());
            break;
        case Reminder.WEEKLY:
            calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, reminder.getInterval());
            break;
        case Reminder.MONTHLY:
            calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, reminder.getInterval());
            break;
        case Reminder.YEARLY:
            calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, reminder.getInterval());
            break;
```

Comment: Did you read the docs ? "Adding events" in "Calendar Provider". Everything is explained in details.

Answer (score 0):

```
The API is 
// Hopefully your alarm will have a lower frequency than this!
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, alarmIntent);
Details : 
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sample code to trigger repeating broadcastReceiver:

```
public static void setRepeaterAlarm(Context context, Class<?> cls, long afterTimeMillis, long intervalTimeMillis) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, cls);
    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long triggerAtTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + afterTimeMillis;
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, triggerAtTime, intervalTimeMillis, pendIntent);
}
```